# Is it possible to make rounded image border with Jasper?

Tags: java, image, jasper-reports

Is possible to apply the effect of rounded image with jasper?

I have searched a lot but I do not find in anywhere how to simply add border-radius to a image in Jasper Report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFIK there is **no** setting in Jasper Report (jrxml) that allows you to add rounded borders directly to your image, *but*

You can add a java class that elaborates the image before adding it to the report

As example I will add [Philipp Reichart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/180740/philipp-reichart)'s metodo from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7603815/5292302) in a class that I called `ImageUtil`

> ```
> package it.jdd;
>
> import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
> import java.awt.Color;
> import java.awt.Graphics2D;
> import java.awt.RenderingHints;
> import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;
> import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
>
> public class ImageUtil {
>   
>   private ImageUtil() {
>       super();
>   }
>   
>   public static BufferedImage makeRoundedCorner(BufferedImage image, int cornerRadius) {
>       int w = image.getWidth();
>       int h = image.getHeight();
>       BufferedImage output = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
>
>       Graphics2D g2 = output.createGraphics();
>       
>       // This is what we want, but it only does hard-clipping, i.e. aliasing
>       // g2.setClip(new RoundRectangle2D ...)
>
>       // so instead fake soft-clipping by first drawing the desired clip shape
>       // in fully opaque white with antialiasing enabled...
>       g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
>       g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
>       g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
>       g2.fill(new RoundRectangle2D.Float(0, 0, w, h, cornerRadius, cornerRadius));
>       
>       // ... then compositing the image on top,
>       // using the white shape from above as alpha source
>       g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcIn);
>       g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);        
>       g2.dispose();    
>       return output;
>   }
> }
> ```

<sup>Quoting whole classes for readability, since the method is taken from Philipp's great answer</sup>

With this class in classpath you can now apply rounded borders to your image

**jrxml example**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="ImageRounded" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="ea1bfa6c-be34-45af-b1cf-1bf35e3f359c">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <title>
        <band height="200" splitType="Stretch">
            <image>
                <reportElement x="20" y="20" width="200" height="153" uuid="ae9f7e0a-84cb-4e3e-8183-5bd00017a4f0"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[it.jdd.ImageUtil.makeRoundedCorner(javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(new java.io.File("C:/testImage.png")),50)]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

**Output**

[image: Example output]